# blender render object from multiple angles

Tags: camera, rendering, blender

I have an object in blender + an HDRI background / environment map. I am using cycles to render the object and I have Blender 2.8.

I would like to take multiple pictures of the rendered object (*with* its background) so that I end up with multiple views of the object (say, about 5/10).

I have seen some posts out there but they're not quite what I want because they just render in solid mode whereas I actually want the whole render.

I am a newbie with blender and I don't even know where to start with this. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can just render multiple pictures by rendering, saving the image then moving the camera and repeating the process again. Or, you could render an animation with the camera moving to different angle and setting the output to an image format.